Why surjectivity implies isogeny is a finite map?
I want to start with some basics, Let $A$ and $B$ be two abelian varieties over $K$. An isogeny is a surjective homomorphism $\phi : A \to B$ with finite kernel.
Isogeny is also defined for elliptic curves or take it as special case of abelian varieties,
Let $E$ and $E'$ be two elliptic curves defined over the field $K$.
A non-zero morphism $\phi$ from $E$ to $E'$ such that $\phi(O_{E}) = O_{E'}$ is called an isogeny.
I take the following sentences from the link Link1. It is actually well known that rational maps between curves are either constant or surjective, an isogeny either maps all of $E$ to $O$, or it is surjective, and in that case must be a finite map.
My first question is: What is the definition of being finite map and why surjectivity implies isogeny must be finite?
My second question is: For special case, I mean for elliptic curves, it is easy to catch that an isogeny is surjective homomorphism and we don't say anything about kernel. However, when we define isogeny for abelian variety, definition consists of the condition that having finite kernel. Conversely, surjectivity can be obtainable for elliptic curves (I mean it is straightforward by definition) on the other hand surjectivity is already given in the definition for abelian variety. Is this just weird to me?
Kindly guide

A map $f:X\to Y$ is finite if there is an open cover of $Y$ by affines $V_i$ so that $f^{-1}(V_i)=U_i$ is affine and the corresponding ring map is finite. (The statement is equivalent to every open cover of $Y$ by affines having this property).
To show that a map $f:X\to Y$ of smooth projective curves is finite if it is non-constant, note that the map must have closed, irreducible image. Since the only closed irreducible subsets of a projective curve are points and the whole space, we must have that $f$ is surjective, and therefore the fiber over every point must be finite (it is a proper closed subset and every proper closed subsets of an irreducible noetherian dimension-one topological space is finite). But then $f$ is also proper, so $f$ is proper and quasi-finite, hence finite. (Alternatively, one can work with function fields and show that $f^{-1}(V_i)$ is the normalization of the ring of functions on $V_i$ inside $K(X)$.)
The reason we specify surjective and finite kernel in the definition of an isogeny is because we want both parts. It happens that one implies the other for elliptic curves, but that's not true when considering more general abelian varieties.

This is really to do with the fact that abelian varieties can have different dimensions, whereas elliptic curves are always $1$-dimensional. For example, inclusion of an abelian variety into a larger abelian variety as a closed subvariety is always finite, but not surjective. Likewise, we could have some projection map from a larger abelian variety to a smaller one, e.g. projection $A \times A \to A$ onto the first factor, which is surjective but not finite. Isogeny should capture the the property of being an "isomorphism near the identity," and neither of these examples work.
For elliptic curves (or maps between complete curves more generally), a morphism is finite iff it is surjective. More generally, a morphism of abelian varieties of the same dimension is surjective iff it is finite.
